# How to convert XML configuration to Java configuration?

Tags: spring

I want to convert this XML configuration to Java but I'm some having trouble finding the correct way to do it..

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
      <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll"/>
    <property name="arguments">
      <util:properties>
        <prop key="key1">value1</prop>
        <prop key="key2">value2</prop>
        <prop key="key3">value3</prop>
        <prop key="key4">value4</prop>
        <prop key="key5">value5</prop>
      </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It is almost working fine but I get an error about the `putAll` method. It should be called on the `Properties` object but with my Java config (see below) it tries to call it on the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` object.

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean getMethodInvokingFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    final MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    final MethodInvokingFactoryBean target = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    target.setTargetClass(System.class);
    target.setTargetMethod("getProperties");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetObject(target);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("putAll");
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("key1", "value1");
    properties.put("key2", "value2");
    properties.put("key3", "value3");
    properties.put("key4", "value4");
    properties.put("key5", "value5");
    final PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(properties);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(propertiesFactoryBean);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
  }
```

So the error I'm getting now is:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.putAll(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean)` because the `putAll` should be called on the `Properties` object.. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm might misunderstand what you want to do, but can it be done bye the following in the setup for your application?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
map.put("key4", "value4");
map.put("key5", "value5");
java.lang.System.getProperties().putAll(map);
```